# How to let console applications not shut down?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a console application, but if the user clicks on the close button, I can prompt and then close it.

[image: console application]

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/545f1768-8038-4f7a-9177-060913d6872f/disable-close-button-in-console-application-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: "Click the closing button"? A console application doesn't have a close button, are you talking about the close button for the console hosting your program? Not sure there is much that can be done about preventing the closing of that. To prevent closing on Ctrl+C you can handle an event on the Console class.

Comment: Brr, good reminder how bad the forums were.  Disabling the close button merely inconveniences the user a bit, he'll type Ctrl+C next.  You can disable that, he'll type Ctrl+Break next.  You can't disable that, you'll have to supply him with a keyboard with the Break key popped off.  He'll plug in another keyboard next.  You'll have to put a lock on the supply closet, he'll use Task Manager next.  You can lock down the PC so that isn't available anymore, he'll dump you as a software supplier next.  The only real thing you can do about it is giving him a good reason to keep the program running.

Comment: If you are talking about close button on the console window, you cannot add a prompt to it as it is controlled by its owner. You can have your own code to ask the user to close or not, by using `if else` loop and `Console.ReadLine()` for user's input.

Comment: Perhaps a better approach is to have a Windows service doing this critical work, and a separate console app just for display purposes, for example "tail" logging of the event stream..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of the program can help you.